# Изменить папку для выходных файлов cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

У меня есть следующий `CMakeLists.txt` для построения библиотеки:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(my_lib)

#...

add_library(my_lib SHARED lib.hpp lib.cpp)
```

Что нужно добавить, чтобы `cmake` генерировал 2 одинаковых `.dll` (или 1, а вторую копировал) в папки других проектов, которые находятся вне текущей папки?

Насколько я понимаю, надо использовать `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` для `.lib` и `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` для `.dll`, но непонятно, как указать нужные мне папки без указания абсолютных путей.

Вот структура папок, чтобы было понятно:

```
my_project
|- my_lib // внутри этой папки по умолчанию появится библиотека, а надо, чтобы
|- user_1 // она была здесь
|- user_2 // и здесь
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вам нужны переменные `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` - каталог сборки для текущего CMakeList и `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` - каталог сборки для корневого CMakeList, для которого был запущен CMake. Через них можно абсолютный путь получить.

Тут нужно помнить, что если у пас проект с подпроектами, то в каталоге сборки будет точно такая же иерархия подпроектов, если вручную ничего не менять.

Возможно, вам нужно не копировать файлы, а искать, как правильно прописывать пути к либам из дочернего проекта в корневом CMakeList (под Linux фокус с ручным копированием не прокатит, например). Я сам с этим пока толком не разобрался, но у меня получалось нормально собирать проекты с зависимостями при помощи [conan](http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) (совместно с CMake)

P.S. Если у вас не проект с подпроектами, нужно просто устанавливать либы после сборки, задавая install prefix.

Answer (score 0):

для программы

```
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Release)
```

для библиотеки

```
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Release)
```

PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR - папка с текущим собираемым проектом